# Get Utc datetime in specific culture independent of my current UI culture

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, cultureinfo

If my application is in Arabic culture then **`DateTime.UtcNow`** gives us arabic clander datetime  like **"13/05/1435 09:40:45 ص"**  but i need it in **en-US** what ever culture is used by my user.

When i am enforce to convert this date to us culture it gives me an error. what is the better way to get **en-US** datetime even in arabic culture like this **"14/03/2014 09:40:45 AM"**.

```
var us = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt",
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

            string st = us.ToString();

            DateTime ddt = Convert.ToDateTime(st,
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

When converting from st to DateTime Again in **en-US** When Application is in Arabic Culture it throw error.
[image]

Mr @lastr2d2

Thanks in advance.

Comment: no, `DateTime.UtcNow` gives you a `DateTime`. `DateTime`'s don't *have* any formatting. When you convert it to a **string** a culture is applied. Don't confuse **formatting** which happens when you convert between strings and `DateTime`s and what is actually being **stored**.

Comment: You shouldn't ever need to convert to a `string` just to then turn around and immediately try to convert it back to a `DateTime`. Why did you think you needed to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you excepted?

```
var ar = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt",
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AE"));
// 14/03/14 06:14:34 ص
var us = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt",
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
// 14/03/14 06:14:44 AM
```

**--Edit**

And you can get the datetime instance by [DateTime.ParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) :

```
var datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(us,"dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss tt",
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: I appreciate your help and really thankful for your responce but problem is that.


            string st = us.ToString();

            DateTime ddt = Convert.ToDateTime(st,
            new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));

when i am converting from string to dateTime again it give error that not possible in arabic culture i am adding snapshot in my question.

Comment: @syedAhsanJaffri I've updated my answer. Please check

Comment: Yes I Know but problem is that DateTime.ParseExact Would Convert I Know but DateTime Would Be "{13/05/35 12:46:05 م}"
Means Arabic Clander date but i want en-US Date Formate in Arabic Culture too like "14/03/2014 09:40:45 AM"

Comment: @syedAhsanJaffri as @Damien said in his comment, `DateTime` don't have any formatting. It's an `object`, what you saw '{13/05/35 12:46:05 م}' is a `String` (result of dateTimeObject.ToString()). The user will never see the `DateTime` object, the only thing they will see is the `String`, which you are in control of generating.

Comment: In short, always use [DateTime.ToString Method (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8tfzyc64(v=vs.110).aspx) and you are fine, you can even create an extension method for that.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting an exception that the string is not recognized as a valid DateTime is because you have explicitly specified the format when formatting to string but have not when you parse. 14/03/14 is ambiguous (which one is the year, which one is the month?) so it can't parse.

You have two options,
 (1) don't explicitly state the format and allow the default which in most cases will be able to be parsed, or 
(2) explicitly state the format when parsing.

In general, parsing dates is hard and getting dates from a user is better handled by a date control. Parsing dates as part of an interchange (to storage, or network) is legitimate but in that case should be governed by international standards (ISO 8601) and not by language specific formats.

I'm wondering too if the issue is that you want to format with a Gregorian calendar and allow the language to be the language of the application, but if so, that's a different question...